# AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet in Django

Tags: python, django

I am completely new to Django.
I've gotten this error when I want to run my `django.cgi`.

Configuration: Python 3.7 and Django 3.1.6.

Error traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "django.cgi", line 80, in &lt;module&gt;
    run_with_cgi(django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler())
  File "/home/lesproh/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 127, in __init__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/home/lesproh/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 40, in load_middleware
    middleware = import_string(middleware_path)
  File "/home/lesproh/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "&lt;frozen importlib._bootstrap&gt;", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "&lt;frozen importlib._bootstrap&gt;", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "&lt;frozen importlib._bootstrap&gt;", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "&lt;frozen importlib._bootstrap&gt;", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "&lt;frozen importlib._bootstrap_external&gt;", line 728, in exec_module
  File "&lt;frozen importlib._bootstrap&gt;", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/lesproh/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py", line 3, in &lt;module&gt;
    from django.contrib.auth.backends import RemoteUserBackend
  File "/home/lesproh/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/backends.py", line 2, in &lt;module&gt;
    from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
  File "/home/lesproh/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in &lt;module&gt;
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/home/lesproh/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 48, in &lt;module&gt;
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/home/lesproh/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 108, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/home/lesproh/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 253, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/home/lesproh/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 136, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

my django app settings

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_mysql',
    'crispy_forms',
    'captcha',
    'django_countries',
    'cigv',
]
CAPTCHA_CHALLENGE_FUNCT = 'captcha.helpers.random_char_challenge'

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'producteur_app.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'producteur_app.wsgi.application'
```

I've getting this error when i want to run my `django.cgi`
configuration: Python 3.7 and Django 3.1.6

Can someone please advise how to proceed? thanks

the code django.cgi

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# encoding: utf-8
import os, sys
import cgi
import cgitb

cgitb.enable()

WWW_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
DJANGO_PROJECT_PATH = os.path.dirname(WWW_PATH)


sys.path.append(DJANGO_PROJECT_PATH + "/cigv/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/")
sys.path.append(DJANGO_PROJECT_PATH + "/cigv/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/")
sys.path.append(DJANGO_PROJECT_PATH + "/cigv/venv/bin/python3")
sys.path.append(DJANGO_PROJECT_PATH + "/cigv/")
sys.path.append(DJANGO_PROJECT_PATH + "/cigv/app/") #TODO: Update me if the name of the Django application is different
sys.path.append(DJANGO_PROJECT_PATH + "/cigv/app/producteur_app/")

def run_with_cgi(application):
    environ                      = dict(os.environ.items())
    environ['wsgi.input']        = sys.stdin
    environ['wsgi.errors']       = sys.stderr
    environ['wsgi.version']      = (1,0)
    environ['wsgi.multithread']  = False
    environ['wsgi.multiprocess'] = True
    environ['wsgi.run_once']     = True
    
    if environ.get('HTTPS','off') in ('on','1'):
        environ['wsgi.url_scheme'] = 'https'
    else:
        environ['wsgi.url_scheme'] = 'http'
    
    headers_set  = []
    headers_sent = []
    
    def write(data):
        if not headers_set:
             raise AssertionError("write() before start_response()")
        
        elif not headers_sent:
             # Before the first output, send the stored headers
             status, response_headers = headers_sent[:] = headers_set
             sys.stdout.write('Status: %s\r\n' % status)
             for header in response_headers:
                 sys.stdout.write('%s: %s\r\n' % header)
             sys.stdout.write('\r\n')
        
        sys.stdout.write(data)
        sys.stdout.flush()
    
    def start_response(status,response_headers,exc_info=None):
        if exc_info:
            try:
                if headers_sent:
                    # Re-raise original exception if headers sent
                    raise AssertionError(exc_info[0], exc_info[1], exc_info[2])
            finally:
                exc_info = None     # avoid dangling circular ref
        elif headers_set:
            raise AssertionError("Headers already set!")
        
        headers_set[:] = [status,response_headers]
        return write
    
    result = application(environ, start_response)
    try:
        for data in result:
            if data:    # don't send headers until body appears
                write(data)
        if not headers_sent:
            write('')   # send headers now if body was empty
    finally:
        if hasattr(result,'close'):
            result.close()


os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'app.producteur_app.settings'  # À modifier
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
run_with_cgi(django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler())
```

Comment: Could you include the contents of the `django.cgi` file

Comment: i've add django.cgi

Comment: First suggestion is to try putting `import django` then `django.setup()` at the top of `django.cgi`